# Web scraping from Google Finance: returned data list always empty

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape data (e.g., market capitalization, PE-ratio, etc.) from Google Finance using the BeautifulSoup-library of Python. However, when I try to extract certain passages (like "div", "tr", "td") from the html-code    of the corresponding Google Finance site, using the "find_all" function, I always receive an empty list (i.e., the "base" object in the code below is empty).

During debugging, I printed the "soup" object and compared its content with the corresponding html-code. What surprised me was that the content of the "soup" object differs from the content of the html-code. I would expect that both should match in order to extract data successfully.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=NASDAQ:GOOGL')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
base = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'ZSM8k'})

print(soup)
print(base)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely up to the server what content it serves you, so the best you can do is to make sure that your request looks like the request sent by the browser as much as possible. In your case, this might mean:

```
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.90 Safari/537.36')]
```

If I am not mistaken, this gives you what you want. You can try to remove irrelevant parts by trial-and-error if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves the issue. Could you explain a bit more why your solution works?

Comment: I wouldn't know for certain; this is just what my Chrome browser sends in the HTTP header (as can be seen in the Devtools). It would seem like Google is inspecting User-Agent in very fine details and serving different CSS accordingly, which kind of makes sense anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As [Imperishable Night](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719984/15164646) said, it's most likely because of not sending proper request headers. [`User-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) is used to act as "real" user visits so websites treat those requests as user requests. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

For example, if you're using [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/) library, the default `user-agent` is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) so websites understand that it's a bot or a script that sends a request, not a real user.

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/web-scraping-from-google-finance-returned-data-list-always-e#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, json
from itertools import zip_longest # https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest


def scrape_google_finance(ticker: str):
    # https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
    params = {
        "hl": "en"
        }

    # https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
    # https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36",
        }

    html = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/finance/quote/{ticker}", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    
    right_panel_data = {"right_panel": {}}
    
    right_panel_keys = soup.select(".gyFHrc .mfs7Fc")
    right_panel_values = soup.select(".gyFHrc .P6K39c")
    
    for key, value in zip_longest(right_panel_keys, right_panel_values):
        key_value = key.text.lower().replace(" ", "_")

        right_panel_data["right_panel"][key_value] = value.text
    
    return right_panel_data
    

data = scrape_google_finance(ticker="GOOGL:NASDAQ") 

print(data["right_panel"].keys())

print(data["right_panel"].get("ceo"))

# output:
"""
dict_keys(['previous_close', 'day_range', 'year_range', 'market_cap', 'volume', 'p/e_ratio', 'dividend_yield', 'primary_exchange', 'ceo', 'founded', 'headquarters', 'website', 'employees'])
Sundar Pichai
'''
```

If you want to scrape more data with a line-by-line explanation, there's a [Scrape Google Finance Ticker Quote Data in Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-finance-ticker-quote-data-in-python/#what_will_be_scraped) blog post of mine.